# Copying an entered string into "ith" element of a string array using strcpy

Tags: c

I am working on a program that a users enters a full name, i am using gets to retrieve the string entered and i need to copy that string into the i-th element in an two-dimension array called name[11][41]. i need to use strcpy to store it. i'm stuck and assistance with this would be great!

[My Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFPWe.png)

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please paste your code into your question, select it, and click `[{}]` button above it to format as code.

Answer (score 0):

Given that your string array is created as indicated:

```
char name[11][41];
```

you can use this to copy up to 40 characters into the *ith* 41 char array, reserving the last space for null termination:

```
//for i from 0 to 10 this will work
strncpy(name[i], "some string", 40);
name[i][40] = 0;//guarantee null termination in case source string is longer than array
```

Answer (score 0):

```
It would be better that there shouldn't be hard code in the code, so you can use defines. It could be helpful to control string length and avoid from segmentation fault problem.

#define MAX_LENGTH 41
#define MAX_INPUT 11
```

In the main:

```
char name[MAX_INPUT][MAX_LENGTH];
char input_name[MAX_LENGTH];
//after filling the input_name
strncpy (name [i],input_name,MAX_LENGTH);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use something like that

```
strcpy(&name[i][0],n);
```